# Comparing youtube view counts between historical release dates

Tags: statistics, metric

I've written a script to use `youtube-dl` to collect all view-counts and ratings from all listed videos on a youtube channel: https://gist.github.com/philshem/ca0b8f964458c63ee4f0e68c0f700f39#file-get_stats-sh

To compare ratings is relatively simple, because they are already averaged. But I would like to compare views, which is not clear to me because the number of views is related to how recently the video was released.

I am looking for a metric that normalizes somehow the age of the video with the number of views. I could do something simple, such as `view_count * days_since_release`, but I don't expect that to be statistically meaningful.

Is there an example metric for comparing historical, cumulative data?

[image: views x rating]

https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1295725069268910081

Comment: ah, maybe this is better on the stats site? https://stats.stackexchange.com/ please migrate, if so!

Answer (score 2):

A simple option would be to use the average number of views per day, this way the value is normalized and independent of how recent the video is. Of course averaging is simplistic, since the views don't follow a linear trend.

A more advanced option would be to model the evolution of views across time (for instance assuming a normal distribution), then estimate the parameters for every particular video and compare the predicted total number of views. This would be more complex due to the difficulty of estimating the parameters from an incomplete distribution.